# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/kaggle/input/CORD-19-research-challenge/comm_use_subset/comm_use_subset/pdf_json' in kaggle

Tags: python, error-handling, kaggle, file-not-found

In kaggle when I use CORD-19-research-challenge dataset, I get this error.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/kaggle/input/CORD-19-research-challenge/comm_use_subset/comm_use_subset/pdf_json'

What should I do to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error is because of the wrong file path. To get the correct file path (structure of the directories), run the below code in the Kaggle notebook:

```
count = 0
for root, folders, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):
   print(root, folders)
```

You will get the below result:
[Screenshot of the Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKbo0.png)

Change the file of the json file paths as

'/kaggle/input/CORD-19-research-challenge/document_parses/pdf_json/'

as shown in the result above. Now re-run the code. It will work.